# No compatible screen mode found, blurry screen

Tags: resolution, display, acer

When I started up my computer one day, the resolution was all blurry and when I logged in it came up with this error message:

```
None of the selected modes were compatible with the possible modes:
Trying modes for CRTC 81
CRTC 81: trying mode 1024x768@61Hz with output at 1440x900@50Hz (pass 0)
CRTC 81: trying mode 800x600@61Hz with output at 1440x900@50Hz (pass 0)
CRTC 81: trying mode 640x480@60Hz with output at 1440x900@50Hz (pass 0)
CRTC 81: trying mode 1024x768@61Hz with output at 1440x900@50Hz (pass 1)
CRTC 81: trying mode 800x600@61Hz with output at 1440x900@50Hz (pass 1)
CRTC 81: trying mode 640x480@60Hz with output at 1440x900@50Hz (pass 1)
```

If anyone can help please do! I can still use Ubuntu but the mouse sometimes goes glitchy.

(I am using an Acer AL1916W A as a display and an AMD Athlon II processor.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can still log into a graphical desktop session, open a terminal window (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>T</kbd>), else change to a tty (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>F1</kbd>) and login. In the terminal, enter `xrandr -q`

The output should look something like this:

```
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 1366 x 768, maximum 32767 x 32767
CRTC connected primary 1366x768+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 344mm x 194mm
   1366x768       60.0*+   39.9  
   1360x768       59.8     60.0  
   1024x768       60.0  
   800x600        60.3     56.2  
   640x480        59.9
```

where in this case, **CRTC** is the output which your monitor is connected to.

Now enter `xrandr --output CRTC --mode 1440x900` (replace CRTC with the correct output if necessary). The output should now have the correct resolution.

To make the changes permanent, you need to put the above command into your .xprofile file.
To do this, type `nano ~/.xprofile` in a terminal. Enter the line `xrandr --output CRTC --mode 1440x900` (remember to use the correct output name) and save (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>O</kbd>, <kbd>Enter</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>X</kbd>).